# Use a javascript variable in css attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the code for a bar. I want to decrease the height of the bar as the bonus time decreases. This is my HTML code for the that bar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

  <script>
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var d =new Date();

    var tl =  currentDate.setTime(currentDate.getTime() + 2*60*1000);
    var seconds =(tl - d)/1000;
    var height = 50;
    function secondPassed() {

      var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
      var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
      if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
      }
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
      if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('bonus').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz";
      } 
      else {
        seconds--;
        height--;
      }
    }
    var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="bonus"  class="hide">
    Time left for <b style="font-size:30px">BONUS</b>: 
    <span   id="countdown" class="timer" style="color:red; font-weight:bold ;font-size:40px "></span>
  </div>

  <section class="main">
    <span class="button-label">Size:</span>
    <input type="radio" name="resize-graph" id="graph-small" /><label for="graph-small">Small</label>
    <input type="radio" name="resize-graph" id="graph-normal" checked="checked" /><label for="graph-normal">Normal</label>
    <input type="radio" name="resize-graph" id="graph-large" /><label for="graph-large">Large</label>   

    <span class="button-label">Color:</span>
    <input type="radio" name="paint-graph" id="graph-blue" checked="checked" /><label for="graph-blue">Blue</label>
    <input type="radio" name="paint-graph" id="graph-green" /><label for="graph-green">Green</label>
    <input type="radio" name="paint-graph" id="graph-rainbow" /><label for="graph-rainbow">Rainbow</label>

    <span class="button-label">Product:</span>
    <input type="radio" name="fill-graph" id="f-none" /><label for="f-none">None</label>
    <input type="radio" name="fill-graph" id="f-product1" checked="checked" /><label for="f-product1">Product 1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="fill-graph" id="f-product2" /><label for="f-product2">Product 2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="fill-graph" id="f-product3" /><label for="f-product3">Product 3</label>

    <ul class="graph-container">
      <li>
      <span>2008</span>
      <div class="bar-wrapper">
        <div class="bar-container">
          <div class="bar-background"></div>
          <div class="bar-inner">25</div>
          <div class="bar-foreground"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </li>

      <li>
      <ul class="graph-marker-container">
        <li style="bottom:25%;"><span>25%</span></li>
        <li style="bottom:50%;"><span>50%</span></li>
        <li style="bottom:75%;"><span>75%</span></li>
        <li style="bottom:100%;"><span>100%</span></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this code there is a countdown timer for bonus. I have also defined a variable height in javascript which decreases as the var seconds decrease. Now I want to use this variable in css. This is my css code:

```
<style>
  input#f-product2:checked ~ .graph-container > li:nth-child(1) .bar-inner { 
    height: 50%; bottom: 0; 
  }
</style>
```

This code only shows that the height of that bar is defined as 50%; but I want to gradually decrease this height by the javascript variable `height`. I tried searching for questions related to this on stackoverflow but it only tells that you can define css property in javascript. I want to do the other way i.e. use javascript variable in css. Or if there is any other way, please suggest.

This code is take from [tympanus.net](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/05/21/animated-3d-bar-chart-with-css3/). This might help in understanding my question better. I just want to change the height of one of these bars in the site according to my countdown timer.

Comment: You can't put js variables in css straight up. If you want to change the height, then do it with js. I would normally suggest adding a class to the body or a top ID but since you need to do this many times, that option is not practical

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit messy, but I can give a very simple example that does what you want (so, not based on the code you gave).

You set an intervaltimer and update the height of a div-element each interval.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Mp7R3/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="bar">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 20px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;

}
#bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

JS:

```
function Bar(element) {
    this.barEl = element;
    this.progress = 100;
}

Bar.prototype.setProgress = function (p) {
    if(p >= 0) {
        this.progress = p;
        this.barEl.style.height = this.progress + "%";
    }
}

var barObj = new Bar(document.getElementById('bar'));
setInterval(function () {
    barObj.setProgress(barObj.progress - 10);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This is what I wanted . The code works perfectly in jsfiddle but not when I copy paste the code . I guess there is some loading error  . I tried $(document).ready(function() { }); after <script> but still the javascript code is not running

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're hoping to use inline JavaScript within your CSS.  That isn't possible, unfortunately.  You'll have to use JavaScript to set the CSS like this:

jQuery:

```
var myJavaScriptVariable = '30%';
$('input#f-product2:checked ~ .graph-container > li:nth-child(1) .bar-inner').css("height",myJavaScriptVariable);
```

Straight JavaScript

```
var myJavaScriptVariable = '30%';
document.querySelector('input#f-product2:checked ~ .graph-container > li:nth-child(1) .bar-inner').style.height = myJavaScriptVariable;
```